# How can I import all symbols from a lua module to the global namespace?

Tags: import, module, lua, love2d

In Python we can type `from math import *` to import all math functions at once.

How can I do similarly in Lua?  I wish to import all symbols from `math`, `love.graphics`, `love.audio`, etc., for convenience when writing small experimental programs.

I'm aware that this is frowned upon.

Comment: My answer would be: Don't. You'd just be giving up the encapsulation that makes the Lua require system so nice.

Comment: Note that in Python, each module has its own global namespace, so importing symbols from a module into your globals is purely a local decision. In Lua, the global namespace is *global* (unless you explicitly give each script its own environment); every script shares it. If you import "all symbols" from a module, then *every* script gets those symbols too. This isn't "frowned upon"; it's using the wrong tool in the wrong language.

Answer (score 3):

While writing the question, I figured out a way to import all symbols from a module:

```
function use(module, ...)
    for k,v in pairs(module) do
        if _G[k] then
            io.stderr:write("use: skipping duplicate symbol ", k, "\n")
        else
            _G[k] = module[k]
        end
    end
end
```

Example usage:

```
require "use"
use(math)
use(love.graphics)

print(sin(pi/6))

function love.draw()
    setColor(1, 0, 0)
    circle("fill", 300, 300, 100)
end
```

Comment: Instead of stderr I'd recommend using `warn`, so you can turn it on or off more easily :D (It's also really more of a warning than an actual error)

Comment: How to "import" function `debug.debug()`?

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer, I was going to use `warn` but it didn't work for me in Love2D, maybe they are using an older Lua or something.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, that `use()` function won't clobber existing symbols, but you could do a special case import, something like `dbg = debug.debug`.